# How to install "boost" in embedded of POSIX

Tags: boost, posix, gnu

I want to put a program into a embedded with POSIX, use its own compiler.
But I need to use the library "boost" for thread and mutex.

Builder: **GNU make builder**

Build coomand: `make MV_COMMON_BASE=.../mdk/common MV_TOOLS_DIR=.../tools MV_BUILD_CONFIG=debug MV_MVDBG_GEN=2`

I did `./bootstrap.sh` in my Ubuntu.
But I don't know how to continue, how to change in `project-config.jam`

How to compile `boost`? 
If need more information, tell me.

Plz,help me
Thanks a lot.....

Comment: It is usually the case that you do not need to compile boost as it is often provided by the operating systems package manager. This is true for ubuntu. Perhaps `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`. I am however unable to help you more than this. Please post a minimal complete verifiable example. See here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Its embedded compiler can't find the include files of system(usr/inlcude).  Although boost has been installed in Ubuntu, however the compiler can't find it, only can copy boost into my project

Comment: There are projects that do this. You want "cross compilation" "toolchain" etc. POSIX has zero to with it